# MySQL performance, subquery using temporary filesort when query uses order by/group by

Tags: mysql

In making the tag tables for an archive of user-created game maps, the SQL for getting the map ids of maps containing all provided tags is, with ... being the tags and # being the number of tags:

```
SELECT DISTINCT map_id 
FROM `map_tag` 
INNER JOIN `tag` USING (tag_id) 
WHERE tag IN (...) 
GROUP BY map_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = #
ORDER BY map_id DESC

/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 83,597  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.032 sec. (+ 0.531 sec. network) */

+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tag     | const | PRIMARY,tag   | tag     | 767     | const |      1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | map_tag | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL  | 888729 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
```

---

I then join the maps themselves and the SQL becomes:

```
SELECT 
    `map`.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT map_id 
    FROM `map_tag` 
    INNER JOIN `tag` USING (tag_id) 
    WHERE tag IN (...) 
    GROUP BY map_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = #
    ORDER BY map_id DESC
) matching 
INNER JOIN `map` USING (map_id)
INNER JOIN `map_tag` USING (map_id) 
INNER JOIN `tag` USING (tag_id) 
LIMIT 0, 10

/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 10  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.297 sec. */

+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                       | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                      |  83597 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | map        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | matching.map_id           |      1 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | map_tag    | ref    | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | matching.map_id           |      2 | Using index              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | tag        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | maps.local.map_tag.tag_id |      1 | Using index              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tag        | const  | PRIMARY,tag   | tag     | 767     |                           |      1 | Using index              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | map_tag    | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                      | 888729 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
```

The problem arises now when I want to actually use the tags.

```
SELECT 
    `map`.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`tag`.tag) AS tags
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT map_id 
    FROM `map_tag` 
    INNER JOIN `tag` USING (tag_id) 
    WHERE tag IN (...) 
    GROUP BY map_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = #
    ORDER BY map_id DESC
) matching 
INNER JOIN `map` USING (map_id)
INNER JOIN `map_tag` USING (map_id) 
INNER JOIN `tag` USING (tag_id) 
GROUP BY map_id
LIMIT 0, 10

/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 10  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 47.641 sec. */

+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                       | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                      |  83597 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | map        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | matching.map_id           |      1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | map_tag    | ref    | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | matching.map_id           |      2 | Using index                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | tag        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | maps.local.map_tag.tag_id |      1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tag        | const  | PRIMARY,tag   | tag     | 767     |                           |      1 | Using index                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | map_tag    | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                      | 888729 | Using where; Using index        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

A 47 second query, up from 0.3 seconds before the `INNER JOIN` to the `map` table. The subquery switches to using temporary and filesort, and I have no idea why. I have indexes set up for the `map_id` in all the relevant tables, but for some reason it doesn't use them when doing the `GROUP BY`. `ORDER BY` also causes this behavior.

Is there something I need to do to alter the tables so that the indexes are used? Is there a more efficient way of bringing the `map` table in and obtaining all tags, not just the ones matching?

---

The goal is to have, if there are three maps (this is not indicative of table structure, `tags` is the `map` to `map_tag` to `tag` table relationship):

```
+-------+---------------+
| name  |     tags      |
+-------+---------------+
| map A | aaa, bbb, ccc |
| map B | bbb, ccc, zzz |
| map C | ccc, zzz, yyy |
+-------+---------------+
```

that if I search for tags "bbb" and "ccc" I get as a result:

```
+-------+---------------+
| name  |     tags      |
+-------+---------------+
| map A | aaa, bbb, ccc |
| map B | bbb, ccc, zzz |
+-------+---------------+
```

with all tags belonging to each map, instead of just the ones matched, and that I am able to sort the  resulting `map` rows by `map` columns without MySQL ignoring the indexes:

```
...
ORDER BY `map`.published DESC

/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 10  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 00:01:35 (+ 0.078 sec. network) */
```

Comment: Can you describe what you want the query to do?

Comment: Sure. The end result is to obtain full rows from the `map` table with a `GROUP_CONCAT` tags field that comprises the tags belonging to the map obtained through the `INNER JOIN`s through the `map_tag` and `tag` tables.

Comment: . . I can read the query.  I don't understand the purpose of the result set.

Comment: The result set is filtered results from the entire `map` table, with the addition of all tags belonging to that row, filtered by provided tags.

Comment: The goal is to be able to put tags in, and get maps with those tags out. I want all of the tags that belong to those maps in their rows so I don't need to query for each of those on top of the original query. I'm sorry if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

Not really understanding what you question, nor answers to comments was, HOWEVER... I would try to structure it this way... Your inner query is a join from map_tag and tags table on the qualifying tags, and the group concat of distinct is done there with the having count grouped by the map id.  Done... Now you can just join to you map table on those that qualified.

To help the index optimizing, I can suggest the following indexes

```
table       index
map_tag     ( map_id, tag_id )
tag         ( tag_id, tag )
map         ( map_id )

SELECT
      m.*,
      PreTags.allTags
   from
      ( SELECT 
              mt.map_id,
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag ORDER BY t.tag SEPARATOR ',') allTags
           FROM 
              map_tag mt
                 JOIN `tag` t
                    ON mt.tag_id = t.tag_id
           group by
              mt.map_id
           having 
              SUM( case when t.tag in (...) then 1 else 0 end ) > 1
           order by
              mt.map_id DESC ) PreTags
         JOIN map m
            ON PreTags.map_id = m.map_id
   limit 
      0, 10
```

This way, the inner query does the group concat for you AND the having so you don't have to reapply it in the outside when getting the final map entries... and since the inner is grouped by the map_id, you would not have duplicates coming from the inner query.

HERE IS ANOTHER OPTION I would be curious of its performance.

```
SELECT
      m.*,
      FullTags.allTags
   from 
      ( SELECT
              Just10.map_id,
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag ORDER BY t.tag SEPARATOR ',') allTags
           from 
              ( SELECT mt.map_id
                   FROM map_tag mt
                   where mt.tag_id in ( select t.tag_id
                                           from `tag` t
                                           where t.tag in (...) )
                   group by mt.map_id
                   having COUNT(*) > 1
                   order by mt.map_id DESC
                   limit 0, 10 ) Just10
                 JOIN map_tag mt2
                    ON Just10.map_id = mt2.map_id
                    JOIN `tag` t
                       ON mt2.tag_id = t.tag_id
           group by
              Just10.map_id ) FullTags
      JOIN map m
         ON FullTags.map_id = m.map_id
```

The inner-most query gets just the max of 10 entries for those that have more than one tag matching that you are looking for an applies the order by.  Then, only for those 10 does it go back and get the group_concat()  -- again, this is just for max of 10 records, then joins finally to get the rest of the map data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem with this solution is that `preTags` only consists of the tags supplied in `AND t.tag in (...)`. It doesn't account for any of the other tags that may belong to the map. If a map has the tags "aaa", "bbb", and "ccc", and I search for `AND t.tag in ("aaa", "bbb")` it will return `PreTags.allTags` as "aaa,bbb" instead of "aaa,bbb,ccc", if that makes sense what I'm looking to achieve.

Comment: @sidke, Yes, that does...  I've revised query for inner to apply HAVING, but get all tags in the group_concat process as a default

Comment: The answer works for getting the concatenated tags in the rows, but it hits the same performance problem that I get with my original approach. Once I throw in an `ORDER BY` for a column on the `map` table, the subquery goes to temporary filesort and slows everything down. 1.7 seconds for your solution to the query without sorting the results by a `map` column, 16.5 seconds when sorting. Definitely a step up from the 47 seconds I was getting before, but I'd like to know why MySQL isn't using the indexes in place only when an `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` come into place.

Comment: @sidke, it is failing on the index because the qualifier is from a specific TAG value in ANOTHER table that you are looking for and not part of an index in the map_tags table to utilize the efficient qualification / order by of the index.  It has to grab EVERY record with counts first, THEN order it.

Comment: @sidke, I revised answer with another possible alternative query and wonder how this query will perform for your needs.